# How to select rows that match the values in a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

This is likely a very simple question, maybe even already answered, but I couldn't find it.
I have two data frames. For simplicity, I'll call them `all` and `index`. `all` will have many columns, one of which I'll call `match`. `index` also has many (other) columns, including `match`. I want to have the rows from `all` that have a `match` value that matches `match` in `index`. Therefore, as a dummy data:

```
all <- data.frame(match = sample(LETTERS, 20),
                  otherStuff = rnorm(20))

index <- data.frame(match = sample(LETTERS, 20),
                    moreStuff = rnorm(20))
```

I've tried the following:

```
all[all$match == index$match,]
```

But this works very badly:

```
> all[all$match == index$match,]
  match otherStuff
3     C -0.6030772

Warning message:
In all$match == index$match :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

As you can see, it gives this warning and, it seems, only considers matches in the same position (in this case, C was the third element in both cases).

After that, I tried something similar with `filter()`, from `dplyr`, just to give it a chance. As I expected, it didn't work. I tried some other things (less logical, actually a little to desperate and nonsense to even comment here), all of which seemed crazy from the getgo. I really don't know what to do here...

Comment: Try: `all[all$match %in% index$match,]`

Comment: It worked like a charm! I didn't knwo this opperator, but I'm guessing it does just that: finds the index of all matches...

Comment: This could be conceptualized an inner join, you could do `merge(all, index["match"])` or `dplyr::inner_join(all, index["match"])`. The simple `%in%` approach makes sense in this case with one column to match on, the join approach generalizes up in case you have multiple columns to match on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is by using `match`:

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
all <- data.frame(match = sample(LETTERS, 10),
                  otherStuff = rnorm(10))

index <- data.frame(match = sample(LETTERS, 10),
                    moreStuff = rnorm(10))
```

Solution:

```
all[match(index$match, all$match, nomatch = 0),]
   match otherStuff
10     Z -0.5558411
5      W -0.4456620
8      Q  0.4007715
6      A  1.2240818
7      K  0.3598138
```